# custom tags in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tags

I am new to MVC and i want to know how to create custom tags in asp.net MVC?

Comment: What do you mean custom tags? As in `<asp:MyControl>` or `Html.MyControl(...)`?

Comment: Could you explain what you'd like to achieve. Maybe you're standing on the wrong foot here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
    public static class HtmlExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString MyTag(this HtmlHelper helper, string tagName, string innerText, Dictionary<string, string> attributes)
        {
            TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder(tagName);
            tag.SetInnerText(innerText);
            tag.MergeAttributes<string, string>(attributes);
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString());
        }
    }
```

and than inside view use it like this:

```
@Html.MyTag("custom", "Text", attributes)
```